# Dynamic JSONP approach

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, prototypejs

I was wondering whether my approach to JSONP is correct and if not, what I can change.

My standard JSONP approach:

**Server**

Standard ?jsonp=callback parameter

**Client**

1. Call the function (example: *jsonp(url, callback)*) *1
2. Create a `<script>` tag *2
3. Execute the script
4. Remove the script tag

**Code**
*Note: I just wrote all of these in the stackoverflow editor, code is untested*
1:

```
jsonp("http://example.com/sampleAPI", function(result) {  
    // Do something  
});
```

2:

```
var callbackID = 0;
var jsonp = function(url, callback) {
    var callbackName = 'callback' + callbackID;
    // put the callback in the URL
    callbackID++;
    if (url.indexOf('?') != -1) {
        url += '&jsonp=' + callbackName;
    } else {
        url += '?jsonp=' + callbackName;
    }

    // create the callback
    window[callbackName] = function(result) {
        $('jsonpScriptElement' + callbackID).remove();
        callback(result);
        window.splice(callbackName);
    }

    // Create the actual element (do this as the last thing because of caching)
    // Assuming prototype.js usage
    $$('body')[0].insert(new Element('script', {'href': url, 'id': 'jsonpScriptElement' + callbackID}));
}
```

Comment: Now that I look at it: maybe I should add an onError on the script tag. I'm sure there are other things that can be changed though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only problem I see with it this is this part:

```
window[callbackName] = function(result) {
    $('jsonpScriptElement' + callbackID).remove();
    callback(result);
    window.splice(callbackName);
}
```

You are making a new function for every call you make. Try to avoid this by making a generic function that is still safe to use asynchronously. Shouldn't be too hard to come up with something. You could for instance pass the sequence number along to the JSONp call and back to the callback so you can keep the different requests apart.

And yes, JSONp is really this easy :P

Additionally you can change your JSONp function to this:

```
var jsonp = (function() {
    var callbackID = 0;
    return function (url, callback) {
         //.. function body ..
    }
}());
```

So you don't have to declare `callbackID` in the global scope